# Sharing media in a removable drive using Windows Media Player

Tags: windows-media-center, xbox360, ps3

I want to play some videos stored in a usb drive connected to my computer in my PS3 or XBox 360.

The files that are in the non-removable drive are shared and I can play them in the PS3 and the XBox but all the content in the removable drive is not available.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1: check that the media on your external drive has been properly shared.  What windows 'says' it has shared, and what is actually visible to others, doesn't always match.

2: look into 3rd party streaming software.  Orb, PS3 Media Server, and MediaTomb are all options that allow you to select exactly what media to stream.

Answer (score 0):

1. Do you have the XBox and PC seeing each other: http://www.microsoft.com/windows/windowsmedia/knowledgecenter/howto/mp11/Xbox360toWMP11XP_StepbyStep.aspx
2. The other issue could be encoding....I had the same issue and I had to re-encode most of my movies in order for my 360 play them.

Comment: the Xbox (and PS3) can already play media from the PC but only the one in the system hard disk, the problem is with the files in a removable drive

Answer (score 0):

is the removable drive formatted in FAT32 format ? you might need to have a FAT32 formatted drive for the systems to recognize the drive.

try conneting your external drive directly to the xbox or ps3 and see if you can access the usb drive .. if you still cannot see it, that means something's funky with your external hdd